# Maximum number (256) of shader global keywords exceeded, keyword Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, oculus, oculusquest

When I try to compile my Unity project, and run it on the Oculus Quest, I get a list of errors:

```
Maximum number (256) of shader global keywords exceeded, keyword _METALLICSMOOTHNESSRANDOMOFFSET_ON will be ignored.
Maximum number (256) of shader global keywords exceeded, keyword _GRAYSCALE_ON will be ignored.
Maximum number (256) of shader global keywords exceeded, keyword _ISANIMATED_ON will be ignored.
Maximum number (256) of shader global keywords exceeded, keyword _LERPSONAR_ON will be ignored.
Maximum number (256) of shader global keywords exceeded, keyword _TOGGLESWITCH0_ON will be ignored.
Maximum number (256) of shader global keywords exceeded, keyword _INVERTCOLORS_ON will be ignored.
Maximum number (256) of shader global keywords exceeded, keyword _STARTPOINTENABLED_ON will be ignored.
```

I just updated Unity to the last version: 2020.1.15f1

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue deleting the ShaderCache files.

Just go to the directory

```
<Your Project Directory>\Library\ShaderCache
```

- Close Unity
- Delete all files in the directory "ShaderCache"
- Open your project

If that doesnt work buy the tool "Shader Control":
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/shader-control-74817